# error upgrading System.Net.Http

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, system.net, system.json

I am currently trying to upgrade many solutions that use a beta version of System.Net.Http (-v 2.0.20126.16343) to version 2.0.20710.0.

I also have a reference to System.Json -v 4.0.20126.16343, however, when I reload the website in a browser I get the error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have checked and the files are in the packages folder, and the bin folder is being populated.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was actually in the cproj file. It just needed to have the reference to the dll updated to the new version number.